How can I determine a linear recurrence relationship given a matrix raised to integer powers?
I'm working on a computational problem where raising a matrix to a large power seems to be the way forward. But repeated matrix multiplication is expensive and I'm looking for some mathematics that might reduce the amount of computation I need to do.
The general problem
I have a square matrix $A$, with $m$ columns and rows, that I am raising the various large powers. After the multiplication the entry in the upper-left corner is of use to me later in the computations. For a given $A$ and positive integer $n$, this number can be calculated
$$x_n = \mathbf{q} A^n \mathbf{q}^T$$
where $\mathbf{q}=[1, 0, 0, \ldots]$ is a vector of length $m$. For the matrix $A$:

it is symmetric
all entries in row $0$ and column $0$ are equal to $1$
all entries on the diagonal --except at $(0,0$))-- are equal to $0$
all other entries are $0$ or $1$

I am hoping to find a way to take a general matrix $A$ and determine an expression I can use to generage values $x_n$.
Some examples
Example 0
The Fibonacci numbers can be generated via matrix multiplication. Seeing the Fibonacci numbers coming out for one of my calculations is what clued me into these matrices possibly being related to recursive relationships. I called this Example "0" because its probably the most well known of my examples.
Example 1
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
   1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
   1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
   1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
   1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
Plugging in various values of $n$:
$$x_1 = \mathbf{q} A^1 \mathbf{q}^T =  1$$
$$x_2 = \mathbf{q} A^2 \mathbf{q}^T =  5$$
$$x_3 = \mathbf{q} A^3 \mathbf{q}^T = 17$$
This goes on to produce the sequence $[1, 5, 17, 63, 227,827\ldots]$ which is A051736 in OEIS and can be calculated using
$x_n = 2x_{n-1} + 6x_{n-2} - x_{n-4}$.
Example 2
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
   1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
   1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
   1 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
Repeating the process above produces $x_n=[1, 4, 13, 43, 142, 469, 1549, 5116, 16897,\ldots]$ which can be calculated by $x_n = 3x_{n-1} + x_{n-2}$. (OEIS A003688)
Example 3
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
Again, repeating the process produces a sequence: $[1, 7, 37, 203, 1103, 6011, 32727, 178237, 970615, 5285789, 28785133,\ldots]$. This sequence is not in OEIS, but a little linear algebra yields $x_n = 3x_{n-1} + 12x_{n-2} + 7x_{n-3} + x_{n-4}$
What I've tried

Brute force calculation. I've used some linear algebra libraries to do the repeated matrix math and read out the values of $x_n$ as I repeatedly multiply $A$ by itself. This works, but is slow.
Diagonalization. Given that $A$ is symmetric, it is diagonalizable to $A = PDP^{-1} \to A^n = PD^n P^{-1}$. This is often faster than the brute force method, but is still expensive (and seems to introduce some floating point errors, but that's beyond the scope of this post). It is still a lot of matrix multiplies per value of $n$ if I want the entire sequence, but it is faster if I just need one $x_n$ for some larger $n$.
Computer Algebra System. This didn't go all that well. But I did try raising matrices to high powers in SymPy. It's very slow and I didn't find any patterns.
Solving for linear coefficients. This works but is not ideal. Like in Example 3 above, sometimes OEIS doesn't have the sequence and so I use the values I've brute-force calculated for to solve for the coefficients of the linear recurrence relation. Once I have a relationship $x_n = k_{1}x_{n-1} + k_{2}x_{n-2} + k_3x_{n-3} + \cdots$ its very fast, but determining the correct $k_i$ requires some guess and check. This is the best method I have so far.

Summary
Is there a relationship between some matrix $A$ and the linear recurrence $x_n = \sum_i k_i x_{n-i}$? Is it possible to quickly determine the $k_i$ from the entries in $A$?

Cayley-Hamilton gives you a linear recurrence of order $m$.

$A^n=A^{n/2}A^{n/2}$, so the brute force is actually $log(n)$ steps

@user619894, this is true, but not as helpful in the case that I need each $A^n$ for $n=1,2,3,4...$ up to some upper limit.

after a few iterations this is dominated by the largest eigenvalue

This much older Q&A seems like it's pretty close to what you want: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/22695/137524

I think I've found an answer to my own question based on some of the comments made on the original question.
$A$ is an $m \times  m$ matrix. Using the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, I can express $A^m$ as:
$$A^m = -c_{m-1}A^{m-1} - c_{m-2}A^{m-2} - c_{m-3}A^{m-3} - \ldots - c_1 A^1 - c_0I_m$$
where $I_m$ is the $m\times m$ identity matrix, and $c_i$ is the coefficient of $\lambda^i$ in the characteristic polynomial of $A$. Multiplying both sides from the left by $A^{n-m}$ yields
$$A^{m-n} A^{m} =A^n = -c_{m-1}A^{n-1} - c_{m-2}A^{n-2} - c_{m-3}A^{n-3} - \ldots - c_1 A^{n-m+1} - c_0A^{n-m}$$
More succinctly:
$$A^n = -\sum_{k=1}^m c_{m-k}A^{n-k} $$
Multiply on the left by $\mathbf{q}$ and by the right on $\mathbf{q}^T$
$$ x_n = \mathbf{q} A^n \mathbf{q}^T = -\sum_{k=1}^m c_{m-k} \mathbf{q}A^{n-k}\mathbf{q}^T  = -\sum_{k=1}^m c_{m-k}x_{n-k}  $$
which is a recursive relationship like I was looking for.
